# RowCount LookupRows Function - Max 2000 Rows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using the following AMPscript:
 `SET @c10 = RowCount(LookupRows(@De1,@band,@value10))`
to retrieve and set the count of the number of rows in a DE. I have now run into an issue where I need to count and display the number of rows which is greater than 2000 rows. Is there a workaround for counting rows greater than 2000?

Answer (score 2):

The [DataExtensionRowCount](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dataextensionrowcount.htm) may help you. This will return the rowcount regardless of size.

```
%%=DataExtensionRowCount("YourDE")=%%
```

If you are looking for a count of a specific subset of your DE, then you will need to look at using the [LookupOrderedRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm) function.

```
%%=RowCount(LookupOrderedRows("Cars",50000,"Horsepower Desc","MPG",Field(@cardata,"MPG"))=%%
```

Given you don't know the number of rows in your DE put a number that is definitely bigger and will return only the number that matches your where clause.